# Add a new object to a multi dimensional array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have a JavaScript object array, as shown below.

```
var satelliteListByGroup = {
    Default: {
        AccessCX1141016091532: {
            name: "IAD_ACS4",
            iname: "IAD_ACS4_core0",
            ra: "[Not assigned]",
            ip: "1.1.1.1",
            status: "Permitted, last connected Jan 14, 2019 10:19:12 AM",
            col: "#ff5555",
            fw: "5.0.0.31",
            srv: "Enabled"
        },
        AccessCX1180424080022: {
            name: "IAD_ACS4",
            iname: "IAD_ACS4_core0",
            ra: "[Not assigned]",
            ip: "1.1.1.1",
            status: "Permitted, last connected Jan 14, 2019 10:19:12 AM",
            col: "#ff5555",
            fw: "5.0.0.31",
            srv: "Enabled"
        }
    }
};
```

I'm trying to add a new second level entry but can't quite figure it out. I've tried a few things similar to this:

```
var arr1 = {
            AccessCX11410160916546: {
                name: "IAD_ACS4",
                iname: "IAD_ACS4_core0",
                ra: "[Not assigned]",
                ip: "5.5.5.5",
                status: "Permitted, last connected Jan 14, 2019 10:19:12 AM",
                col: "#ff5555",
                fw: "5.0.0.31",
                srv: "Enabled"
            }
        };
        satelliteListByGroup.Default.push(arr1);
```

In this instance **push** isn't valid. It only seems to work with the main array name.

Comment: What is the resulting data looks like? Can you update your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`push()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) is a array method, but `Default` is not an array, it is an object. You can use [`Object.assign()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign):

> The [`Object.assign()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) method is used to copy the values of all enumerable own properties from one or more source objects to a target object. It will return the target object.

```js
var satelliteListByGroup = {
    Default: {
        AccessCX1141016091532: {
            name: "IAD_ACS4",
            iname: "IAD_ACS4_core0",
            ra: "[Not assigned]",
            ip: "1.1.1.1",
            status: "Permitted, last connected Jan 14, 2019 10:19:12 AM",
            col: "#ff5555",
            fw: "5.0.0.31",
            srv: "Enabled"
        },
        AccessCX1180424080022: {
            name: "IAD_ACS4",
            iname: "IAD_ACS4_core0",
            ra: "[Not assigned]",
            ip: "1.1.1.1",
            status: "Permitted, last connected Jan 14, 2019 10:19:12 AM",
            col: "#ff5555",
            fw: "5.0.0.31",
            srv: "Enabled"
        }
    }
};

var arr1 = {
            AccessCX11410160916546: {
                name: "IAD_ACS4",
                iname: "IAD_ACS4_core0",
                ra: "[Not assigned]",
                ip: "5.5.5.5",
                status: "Permitted, last connected Jan 14, 2019 10:19:12 AM",
                col: "#ff5555",
                fw: "5.0.0.31",
                srv: "Enabled"
            }
        };
Object.assign(satelliteListByGroup.Default, arr1);
console.log(satelliteListByGroup);
```

Comment: Object.assign is for creating a copy of object, there is no need to create a copy of object here. You should simply set a property to existing project

Comment: @KomalBansal, right now there is one object, what if there is multiple? Will you do that one by one?

Answer (score 0):

push is not a valid syntax to add a new key to object. In your case `arr1` is an object. So use `Object.keys` to get the key and `Object.values` to get the key and values from `arr1` object. Both Object.keys and Object.values return an array. Since `arr1` contains only one value you can access it using the index.

Then use square bracket to create the key inside `Default` object

```js
var satelliteListByGroup = {
  Default: {
    AccessCX1141016091532: {
      name: "IAD_ACS4",
      iname: "IAD_ACS4_core0",
      ra: "[Not assigned]",
      ip: "1.1.1.1",
      status: "Permitted, last connected Jan 14, 2019 10:19:12 AM",
      col: "#ff5555",
      fw: "5.0.0.31",
      srv: "Enabled"
    },
    AccessCX1180424080022: {
      name: "IAD_ACS4",
      iname: "IAD_ACS4_core0",
      ra: "[Not assigned]",
      ip: "1.1.1.1",
      status: "Permitted, last connected Jan 14, 2019 10:19:12 AM",
      col: "#ff5555",
      fw: "5.0.0.31",
      srv: "Enabled"
    }
  }
};

var arr1 = {
  AccessCX11410160916546: {
    name: "IAD_ACS4",
    iname: "IAD_ACS4_core0",
    ra: "[Not assigned]",
    ip: "5.5.5.5",
    status: "Permitted, last connected Jan 14, 2019 10:19:12 AM",
    col: "#ff5555",
    fw: "5.0.0.31",
    srv: "Enabled"
  }
};
let getKey = Object.keys(arr1);
let getVals = Object.values(arr1);

satelliteListByGroup.Default[getKey[0]] = getVals[0]
console.log(satelliteListByGroup)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are setting property of object , not push an element in array.
Try this-

```
    obj  ={
       'AccessCX11410160916546':{
        name: "IAD_ACS4",
        iname: "IAD_ACS4_core0",
        ra: "[Not assigned]",
        ip: "5.5.5.5",
        status: "Permitted, last connected Jan 14, 2019 10:19:12 AM",
        col: "#ff5555",
        fw: "5.0.0.31",
        srv: "Enabled"
    },
   'AccessCX114101890900-':{
        name: "IAD_ACS6",
        iname: "IAD_ACS4_core2",
        ra: "[Not assigned]",
        ip: "5.5.5.5",
        status: "Permitted, last connected Jan 14, 2019 10:19:12 AM",
        col: "#ff5555",
        fw: "5.0.0.31",
        srv: "Enabled"
    },

   }
for(let key in obj){
 satelliteListByGroup.Default[key]= obj[key];
}
```